# Validate against repeater items

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, repeater

I have a page which has a panel with a repeater items displayed on it which comes from a database table. Here's the code to display the items:

html:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelLightRefreshmentsExpanded" runat="server">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptLightRefreshments" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label ID="lblItem" Text="Item" runat="server"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:Label ID="lblUnitPruce" Text="Unit Price" runat="server"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" Text="Quantity" runat="server"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:Label ID="lblUnitPriceTotal" Text="Total" runat="server"></asp:Label></th>
           </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' OnClick="lnkSubmit_Click" CommandArgument='<% Eval("ID").ToString() %>' ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cost") %>' ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatorLightRefQuantity" runat="server" ErrorMessage='<%# "Quantity must be a minimum of " + Eval("MinQuantity") %>' ControlToValidate="txtQuantity"
            MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue='<%# Eval("MinQuantity") %>' CssClass="validator" Text="*" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPriceTotal" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" CssClass="grey" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'></asp:TextBox>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="panelLightRefreshmentsExpanded_CollapsiblePanelExtender" 
    runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="panelLightRefreshmentsExpanded">
</asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

code behind:

```
SqlCommand lightRefreshmentsCommand = new SqlCommand();
                    lightRefreshmentsCommand.Connection = itemsConnection;
                    lightRefreshmentsCommand.CommandText = "select * from table where LocationAvailable LIKE '%" + site + "%' AND ItemType = 'Light refreshments' ";

SqlDataReader lightRefreshmentReader = lightRefreshmentsCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        rptLightRefreshments.DataSource = lightRefreshmentReader;
                        rptLightRefreshments.DataBind();
                        lightRefreshmentReader.Close();
```

The items are catering items and in some cases a user should only be able to select one option. So for example for light refreshments if the repeater items were as follows:

- Sandwiches
- Soup
- Finger Buffet 1
- Finger Buffet 2
- Finger Buffet 3

A user should only be able to select one of the finger buffet options. I was going to add validation but as far as I can see you can only validate one row (ie make sure all fields on one row have an entry). Is it possible to validate against more than one row on a list of repeater items? I can't see how you would do this. Or is there another way to go about this.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

This is an example of the kind of help articles I've found however they have only show how to use the custom validator to validate one row not how to validate one row against another.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptItem_ItemDataBound">
  <HeaderTemplate>
      <table>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectItem" runat="server" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtToValidate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </td>
          <td>
              <asp:CustomValidator ID="cValidation" runat="server"     ClientValidationFunction="MyClientValidation"
                  ErrorMessage="Invalid"></asp:CustomValidator>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
```

```
protected void rptItem_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
      CheckBox chkSelectItem = e.Item.FindControl("chkSelectItem") as CheckBox;
      TextBox txtToValidate = e.Item.FindControl("txtToValidate") as TextBox;
      CustomValidator cValidation = e.Item.FindControl("cValidation") as CustomValidator;

      if (chkSelectItem != null && txtToValidate != null && cValidation != null)
      {
          ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(cValidation.ClientID, "chkId", chkSelectItem.ClientID);
          ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(cValidation.ClientID, "txtId", txtToValidate.ClientID);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add a customvalidator and do the validation there.

Comment: Thank you Kiran. This is what I thought but I can only see how to validate the controls in one row not how to validate one row against another. I've updated my question to show an example of the type of articles I've read. If you know how to validate one row against another would you be able to provide an example. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To validate data against multiple rows you have to add a custom validator to the form. You need to add this out side the repeater control

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cValidation" 
              runat="server"      
              OnServerValidate="cValidation_ServerValidate"
              ErrorMessage="Invalid">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

In the validation function repeat through all the rows from the repeater and do your validation logic

```
protected void cValidation_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    //Here you can loop through each item
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptLightRefreshments.Items)
    {
        //
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //Get the controls
            Label lblItem = item.FindControl("lblItem") as Label;
            TextBox txtQuantity = item.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;
            //Do your validation
        }
    }
    //Finally set the result to args
    args.IsValid = isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this Kiran. I have added the custom validator outside of the repeater control and the ServerValidate to the code behind but am getting the error CS1061: 'ASP.page1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'cValidationServerValidate' and no extension method 'cValidationServerValidate' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.page1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  Any ideas why I am getting this?